# Function return empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, return, append

I would like to make a loop to create a dataframe that gathers the lines of an input dataframe, which have common points.
My problem : When I apply the function, the output dataframe is empty...
yet with a print (output) in the loop, we see that the program works .. I do not understand, i tried to change return position but that doesn't work

Thank you in advance for your help !

```
def group (dataframe, identifiant, output):
    for i in range(len(identifiant)):
        ident = identifiant.loc[i,"IDCTV"]
        # print(ident)


        for j in range(len(dataframe)):
            if dataframe.loc[j,"IDCONTREVENANT"] == ident:
                di = dataframe.loc[j, "DATE_INFRACTION"]
                nt = dataframe.loc[j,"NOTRAIN"]
                genre = dataframe.loc[j,"CODEETATCIVIL"]
                age = dataframe.loc[j,"AGE"]
                # print(di, nt, genre, age)

            for k in range(len(dataframe)):
                if k != j :
                    if dataframe.loc[k,"DATE_INFRACTION"] == di and dataframe.loc[k,"NOTRAIN"] == nt:
                        idgroup = dataframe.loc[k,"IDCONTREVENANT"]
                        genreidgroup = dataframe.loc[k,"CODEETATCIVIL"]
                        ageidgroup = dataframe.loc[k,"AGE"]
                        output = output.append({ "IDREF" : ident ,"CODEETATCIVILREF" : genre,"AGEREF" : age ,"IDCTV" : idgroup,"CODEETATCIVILCTV" : genreidgroup,"AGECTV" : ageidgroup}, ignore_index = True)
                        print(output)
    return output

group(df,IDCTV,df_groups)

print(df_groups)
```

Comment: Is it exactly like that in your code? Because you need to indent everything below the def line.

Comment: thk's for answer 
yes it's like that,  i can't indent everything below the def line because my loops are in loops

Comment: Why does that prevent you from indenting it? Python requires you to indent lines that are in a function.

Comment: Ho sorry, you're right, no my code is not like this, i've the indents below def, no problems with that.

Comment: Thus, i don't know what is the problem ...

Comment: try initializing output before the for loops. Could just be    output = pd.DataFrame()    right under the def line

Comment: I tried but always empty dataframe ...

Comment: Wait, the last two lines, you print df_groups but never assign anything to it. Seems like you should probably say df_groups=group(......)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to change

```
group(df,IDCTV,df_groups)
```

to

```
df_groups = group(df,IDCTV,df_groups)
```

Right now you're calling the `group` funciton and doing all that calculation, but you're not saving the output anywhere. So when you run `print(df_groups)` it prints out whatever it was before you called the function.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for this begin' mistake.